# Can I dual boot two separate instances of Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, dual-channel

I have two licences for W10 64 pro and I would like to dual boot them so that I have one fully updated internet-accessed side and one which is not on the net and has no updates installed. This would enable me to continue to use my home recording software, which update 1709 has trashed, in isolation from updates. I have a spare partition ready but my W10 only wants to re-install over my c drive and I get no custom install option to select a different partition.

Comment: If it is specifically for just one software package, I would recommend using a Virtual Machine such as Hyper-V or Oracle VirtualBox. You can then use the software from your updated install at will, and it will be a lot easier to setup.

Comment: Can you do this?  I suppose you can do it, but eventually you will be required to upgrade from 1703 to 1709.  Feature upgrades are required if you have Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional installed.  Additionally, only Windows 10 Professional allows you to defer feature updates, but that only is allowed for a specific amount of time.  I don't see how you will accomplish keeping the same system, off the internet, and avoid that fate,  **If kept off the internet you an use 1703 or whatever version until the end of time.**

Comment: @Ramhound It's quite easy to disable updates entirely on Pro. Not recommended on a net-connected machine, but still easy.

Comment: @Ramhound not entirely true. The upgrades are also delivered through Windows Update. If you disable the Windows Update service completely, you can effectively stop the entire update process and still be connected to the internet. It will not be safe, but it can be done.

Comment: @Bob you can even disable the services on home. So it can also be done on other versions besides Pro. But yeah, not recommended for a net-connected machine.

Comment: @Bob - My comment is based on the fact, you want to receive security updates, and by allowing that to happen, eventually the feature update will be installed.

Comment: @LPChip - I am aware.  I choose to explain how to disable the Windows Update service.  As a semi-security buff, that is a non-starter for me, wish I had more time for my passion.

Comment: dont use the windows repair disk or anything like that. If you want a separate edition of windows 10 pro, use either a vm like virtualbox, or download and install a fresh copy of windows 10 from the windows 10 media creation tool.